# SQL Server : not able to insert into table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am not sure this an syntax error or a problem with my IDE (Visual Studio), but I can't seem to `insert into` the table I have added to my project.

```
private void create_user_username_box_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add user/password to database when when someone leaves the area. 
    using (DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (DbCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[information] (id, password) VALUES (@id, @pw);"))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", create_user_username_textbox.Text));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pw", create_user_password_textbox.Text));

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }                
    }                
}
```

When I leave the textbox, I seem to get an error message stating

> Invalid object name 'dbo.information'

when in fact the table is created as such in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[information]
(
    [Id] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [password] NVARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

So why is it a wrong name?

Comment: You created a user table in master!?

Comment: And the table really is created within the `master` database?

Comment: Never store plain text passwords

Comment: I am a noob...  What should I had done?

Comment: Do not do anything in database master, this is a system database. Create your own and then create the table there. Reference that database from your connection string. Do not forgot to give your user (that you use in the connection string) access to the database/table.

Comment: You should make a new database for your app and put any tables etc in there

Comment: There are many things that are not great here. Using the master database for anything, plain text passwords, password is allowed to be NULL. Ambiguous table and column names. Also, think you would be better using a button and a click event instead of when the user leaves a textbox.

Comment: This is a dummy project, so just for fun...  I guess I will look into it when i get this fixed..but anywhere i can read about this?... i seem to be missing something on how to handle things..

Comment: Take another look in VS  on where this table is. I bet on wrong sql server `INSTANCE` name or `DATABASE` name. Your table is probably in Northwind or whatever db. Not in `master`. So change it in your connection string after discovering proper db name.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here could be a connection string issue.

Going off this example you are using a local database, here is an example connection string I have used in the past.

```
connectionString ="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"
```

With initial catalog being the database name, and `integrated security = true` indicating to use windows authentication to the database.

So in your example it would look like this:

```
connectionString ="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Like others mentioned in the comments don't create tables in the master database again, always create a new one.

And another note, a personal touch would be to look into [configuration manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) for you to store connection strings in, then you can easily call the connection string from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `master` database on your conection string.

You can change `master` for your own database:

`Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;`

`Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=MyDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`